# Migration repository from VSS to SVN: 9 hours delay in the commits' date in the log file

Tags: svn, migration, visual-sourcesafe, polarion

I have successfully migrated a VSS repository into SVN, using Polarion SVN Importer.

**Problem** - The only problem is that all the changes occurring in the VSS history are reported, but checking their dates they look to be delayed exactly by 9 hours forward.

Authors, minutes and seconds of the commits are right, but the hours (and so far also the day, if the delay causes the date to overcome the midnight) are moved 9 hours forward.

**Note** - I have made some tests and this is independent by the clock of the Operating System I'm using.

Any suggestion about what may be the cause or the solution?

Comment: I don't really understand why this question got close vote. It seems to be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something went wrong during the migration. In Subversion, revision's date and time is stored as [`svn:date` unversioned property](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.ref.unversioned). The property `svn:date` per SVNBook:

> Contains the UTC time the revision was created, in ISO 8601 format. The value comes from the server machine's clock, not the client's.

Therefore, it seems that the import / migration tool you used set the time wrong. I'd suggest checking this tool's options and re-import the repository. However, there is another option -- you could rewrite `svn:date` value for all revisions. However, this may require some non-trivial scripting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is I can't find where my tool has set this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I had to set in the right way the time zone in the VSS repository through VSS Administration tool (MIcrosofot Visula Source Safe Administration).